# El código se salta un printf

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo C y estaba haciendo un programa que te regresa tu edad ingresando tu fecha de nacimiento.

Aunque lo principal funciona, hay un `printf` que te pide tu genero ingresando una `F` o `M` (dependiendo tu género) para que al final te regrese tu género en la respuesta.

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo el programa se salta el pedir el género y pasa directamente a pedir la fecha de nacimiento, y no comprendo por qué.

Éste es el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int edad,año;
char nombre[24],sexo;
printf("Teclea tu nombre:");
scanf("%s", & nombre);
printf("Teclea su sexo\n M masculino \n F femenino \n\a");
scanf("%d",&sexo);
printf("Teclea tu año de nacimiento: ");
scanf("%d",&año);
edad=2022-año;
printf("La persona de sexo %c de nombre %s en el 2022 tendra %d años", sexo, nombre, edad);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se me hace haber visto una pregunta cómo esta. Mira si no hay otra con una respuesta que te ayude.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos qué entorno de desarrollo y compilador usas? Además, como pista, te diría que el formato `%d` no es el más adecuado para obtener y almacenar un dato de tipo `char`, más bien es para números enteros.

Comment: Uso Dev C++, ya intente cambiar el %d por %c pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Teóricamente Dev C++ usa g++ para compilar, pero no encuentro la opción adecuada para compilar este código C usando identificadores con juegos de caracteres como Unicode o UTF-8. Voy a transliterar tu código para poder compilarlo y te explico lo que te pasa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un problema con el procesamiento que hace `scanf` de las cadenas de caracteres.

Almacenará el texto en tu cadena (ojo, alerta de desbordamiento de memoria) y dejará el retorno del carro sin procesar en la entrada estándar.

Para solucionarlo tienes dos opciones:

- Usar un espacio delante de `%c` para que se eliminen los caracteres en blanco adicionales que se reciban previamente.
- Usar `gets()` para obtener la cadena de caracteres.

---

En la primera opción tendrías lo siguiente:

```
scanf("%s", nombre);
printf("Teclea su sexo\n M masculino \n F femenino \n\a");
scanf(" %c", &sexo);
```

En esta solución estamos usando la directiva "espacio en blanco" que permite filtrar el retorno del carro sobrante de la línea anterior.

En el manual puedes ver qué se considera una directiva y cómo funciona el espacio en blanco:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

> **A directive is one of the following:**
>
> - A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.;
>   see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.

En castellano:

> **Una directiva es uno de las siguientes:**
>
> - Una secuencia de caracteres de espacio en blanco (espacio, tabulador, nueva línea, etc), etc.;
>   ver isspace(3)). Esta directiva coincide con cualquier cantidad de espacios, incluyendo ninguno, en la entrada.

---

En el segundo caso lo siguiente:

```
fgets(nombre, 23, stdin);
/* Quitamos la nueva línea extra */
size_t longitud = strlen(nombre);
if((longitud > 0) && (nombre[longitud - 1] == '\n')) {
    nombre[longitud - 1] = '\0';
}
printf("Teclea su sexo\n M masculino \n F femenino \n\a");
scanf("%c",&sexo);
```

Esta segunda opción es más segura desde el punto de vista de desarrollo ya que evitas el riesgo de desbordamiento de memoria, aunque tenga el inconveniente de tener que eliminar el carácter de nueva línea adicional.

Comment: Al hacer el `-Wall` me lanzó advertencia de incompatibilidad de punteros. Se podría solucionar como hice en la edición inicial o, simplemente, quitando el `&` (como ha visto en tu respuesta :).

Answer (score 2):

**Error #1** Los strings no necesitan referencia

```
char nombre[24];
scanf("%s", & nombre);
```

`scanf` necesita que se le pasen punteros a las variables, eso le permite modificar el valor de tus variables. Lo que sucede es que un array `char[]` ya es un puntero en si mismo, luego no necesita que uses referencias en este caso. El uso correcto sería:

```
scanf("%s", nombre);
```

**Error #2** Usa los modificadores adecuados a cada tipo de variable.

```
char sexo;
scanf("%d",&sexo);
```

En este caso `sexo` es de tipo `char` pero tu le dices a `scanf` que lea un entero. Aquí tenemos un problema bastante gordo, ya que `sexo` ocupa únicamente un byte, mientras que el tipo `int` ocupa 4. Esto quiere decir que el programa sobreescribirá 3 bytes que no pertenecen a tu variable. Puedes estar modificando otros valores sin darte cuenta.

Si `sexo` es `char`, entonces lee un `char`:

```
scanf("%c", &sexo);
```

Ahora bien, esta línea que te acabo de poner introducirá un nuevo error, y es que el programa aparentará hacer caso omiso a esta línea y avanzará sin esperar a que introduzcas ningún valor. Esto se debe a que la lectura anterior, la del string, deja un salto de línea en el buffer de entrada ... y ese mismo salto de línea es el que se va a almacenar en `sexo`. Para evitar esto hay que dejar un espacio antes de la lectura:

```
scanf(" %c", &sexo);
```

De esta forma, `scanf` descartará cuantos saltos de línea, tabuladores o espacios haya antes del dato que tu vas a introducir.

Esto no sucede cuando lees otros tipos de datos porque la función sobreentiende que, por ejemplo, un entero no va a empezar por un espacio. Sin embargo cuando quieres leer un caracter, la función no puede decidir por ti si te interesa o no el salto de línea que puede encontrarse ahí